# Get feature names for best_estimator in GridsearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I've tried to use `GridsearchCV` on a Ridge model, where I use `PolynomialFeatures` in my preprocessing pipeline. When I have trained/fitted the model I can access the coefficients for the best model via:

```
pipe = Pipeline(
    [
        ("column_preprocessor", preprocessor),
        ("estimator", Ridge(max_iter=10000)),
    ]
)

gridsearch = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid, n_jobs=-1)

gridsearch.best_estimator_.named_steps.estimator.coef_
```

And this gives an array of values. However, since I have been using `PolynomialFeatures` I would actually like to know which feature each of these values corresponds to. I've tried something like:

```
gridsearch.best_estimator_.feature_names_in_
```

But this just gives the names of the original data frame, i.e. not with the interaction and polynomial terms.

So, is there any way to get out ALL the features for my best estimator ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

scikit-learn preprocessors provide a [`get_feature_names_out`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html#sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.get_feature_names_out) (or `get_feature_names` in older versions, now deprecated) which returns the names of the generated features in a format like `['x0', 'x1', 'x0^2', 'x1^2', 'x0 x1']`. Optionally, a list of input names can be passed as argument to use them in returned output names.

```
gridsearch.best_estimator_.named_steps.column_preprocessor.get_feature_names_out()
```